# How can I make Redux Action Creator return promise?

Tags: react-redux

I am trying to grasp how to return a promise from a Redux Action Creator. 
I have read these two articles, but are none the wiser. Maybe I'm just daft. ;)

https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware
https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/returning-promises-from-redux-action-creators-3035f34fa74b

1. My component calls the action called `startCreateNote()`
2. The action calls the database API
3. The database operation finishes and resolves an object {newlyCreated-id, reduxStoreObject}
4. the Action Creator is dispatched
5. Now I wish to wait for the Redux Action Creator to resolve before proceeding
6. Show toaster after Action Creator has resolved

See code below.

```js
    //ADD_NOTE action generator
    export const addNote = (id, note) => ({
      type: ADD_NOTE,
      id,
      note
    })
    export const startAddNote = (noteData = {}) => {
      return (dispatch, getState) => {
        //Database API Instruction object
        const apiInstruction = { action: DB_ACTION_ADD, payload: noteData, uid: getState().auth.uid }
        //Call database API to insert Note into Database
        return noteDatabaseAPI(apiInstruction)
          .then(({id, reduxStoreObj}) => {
            //The database API resolves id of newly created Note & reduxStore object 

            //THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE!
            dispatch(addNote(id, reduxStoreObj)).then(
              toast("New note saved!")
            ).catch(
              toast.error("ERROR - Note was not saved!")
            )
          }).catch( (err) => {
            //This gets triggered with error message:
            //database fail! - TypeError: "dispatch(...).then is not a function"
            console.log('database fail! -', err)
          })
      }
    }
```

How can I make my Action Creator return a promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand the (probably) easiest way to make the action creator return a promise is by using one of several asynchronous-operations libraries such as:

- redux-saga
- redux-thunk
- redux-observable
- redux-promise
- redux-loop
- redux-ship
- redux-logic
- redux-effects
- redux-cycles
- redux-side-effects

I found more information here: https://decembersoft.com/posts/what-is-the-right-way-to-do-asynchronous-operations-in-redux/#redux-saga

Answer (score 0):

A clean and easy way to do what you're trying to do is via your reducer.

You could start with adding a `isNoteSaved` variable in your reducer as follows.

```
    case ADD_NOTE_REQUEST:
        return {
            ...state,
            isNoteSaved: false
        }

    case ADD_NOTE_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            isNoteSaved: true
        }

    case ADD_NOTE_FAILURE:
        return {
            ...state,
            error: action.payload,
            isNoteSaved: false
        }
```

Your `isNoteSaved` variable has an initial state of `false`.

Then in place of your promise, you could add something like this :

```
toast() && addNoteReducer.isNoteSaved
```

It means your function will be executed when `isNoteSaved` is true.
That's how I do it. Adding promises to action creators adds complexity and makes the code less readable.